# Activating and deactivating `while` loop with 2 mouse buttons

Tags: c++, loops, winapi, button

I want to activate a while loop with 2 mouse buttons.

The first button should start and stop it and the second one should stop and reset it.

It works, but I can't reset the first button.

I tried a lot of  `GetKeyState()` and `GetAsyncKeyState()` variants.

```cpp
bool loopy = false;

int main()
{
    while (true) {
        if (GetKeyState(VK_XBUTTON2) > 0) {
            loopy = true;
        }
        else {
            loopy = false;
        }

        if (GetKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1) < 0) {
            loopy = false;
            // BYTE keystate[256] = { 0 };
            // SetKeyboardState(keystate);
        }

        if (loopy) {
            // do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for [GetKeyState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeystate) explains, why this won't work. The more important lesson is this: Cheating in games is generally **much** harder than learning to play or investing time.

Comment: You don't have a message loop, so `GetKeyState()` will not work, you will have to use `GetAsyncKeyState()` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution if anybody is interested :)

```cpp
bool loopy = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == WM_XBUTTONDOWN) {
        if (HIWORD(((PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->mouseData) == XBUTTON2)
        {
            loopy = !loopy;
            return true;
        }
        else if (HIWORD(((PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->mouseData) == XBUTTON1)
        {
            loopy = false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (loopy)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);

    CreateThread(0, 0, ThreadProc, 0, 0, 0);

    while(GetMessage(0, 0, 0, 0));

    ExitProcess(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

the key part is this: loopy = !loopy;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Flunte I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.